# Extract sql server 2017 install file with Powershell

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell

I would like to download the sql server 2017 install file from Microsft, link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853017 and if you also download this file you will notice that this is just a 4.8 mb file. When running it, and select to download the media for the full install, it will download a 700 mb file called "SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe"

While this is an exe, it basically just unzips all its contents.

I have tried to use Powershell to silently unzip:

```
start-process C:\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe -Argumentlist "/a"
```

however it still brings up the prompt asking me to select zip location.

Is there a way to unzip this file silently (i.e just supply the desired path and automate it all from PS)?

*Edit: This is an environment where I wouldn't be able to use 7zip

Comment: Using start-process is the same as calling the executable directly: `C:\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe /extract: c:\temp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to script out the extracting of the full installation media for SQL Server Express. The purpose of that file is for user and ease of installation, it was not designed for strict script install.

If you are looking to get the media for doing an automated installation of SQL Server Express, then simply run the extract one time and you have it. Once the media is extracted then you can copy that directory and work on automating the installation.

Answer (score 1):

100% worked

```
SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe /extract /X:"%TEMP%\mssql" /q && ping 127.0.0.1 -n 30 && %TEMP%\mssql\setup.exe /ACTION=Install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
start-process "C:\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe" -Argumentlist "/extract: `"c:\temp`""
```

Comment: Using `start-process` is the same as calling the executable directly: `C:\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe /extract: c:\temp`. Besides, you can't extract the full installer from the *web* installer

Answer (score 0):

Try this c:\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe /X /q